# Calculating time difference between two dates picked with datapicker

Tags: javascript

I've got a option for users to select two dates, then it should display the difference between the two.

```
function calculateDate() {
   var dateDom1 = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
   var dateDom2 = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
   var date1 = Date.parse(dateDom1);
   var date2 = Date.parse(dateDom2);

   var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
   var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
   console.log(diffDays);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I get

> InternshipDetails:880 Uncaught TypeError: date2.getTime is not a
>   function

in the inspector console

Comment: Do you have a demo that has this error? Most probably `date2` isn't a Date object.

Comment: Date.parse(new Date(dateDom2)) use this for var date1 & date2

Comment: Date.parse   returns  A number representing the milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date.parse` return time in ms

so you should do something like this:

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

instead this:

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```